# How to generate a cosine wave with signal generator in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to generate a power spectrum by modeling like the figure: [image]

I would like to generate a simple cosine wave: $\cos(2\pi t)$, using a signal generator.
However, I could not find a phase shift. I even looked upon the MATLAB Document, but it seemed that the generator cannot produce a cosine wave as it only has amplitude and frequency settings. However, I am required to use the generator for modeling. So What I want to ask is "Is it possible to produce a cosine wave with signal generator only?"

Comment: I think that you can use a delay element to produce a phase shift.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simulink

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulink